# If something is a proper subset of one of the elements of a set is that something a subset of the overall set(Example in the question}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Example: if $\{a , \{b,c\}\}$ is the set then is $\{b\}$ a subset of the set?

I'm asking this because the cardinality of a power set is $2^n$ where $n$ is the number of elements in the original set. The only way I see this as being possible is if the example I stated above isn't true.

Note: the set in the example above has 2 elements, not 3 right?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions, $\{b\}$ is not a subset of $\{a, \{b, c\}\}$. In order for this to be the case, we would need every element of $\{b\}$ (i.e. just the element $b$) to belong to the set $\{a, \{b, c\}\}$. As you pointed out, this set has two elements: $a$ and $\{b, c\}$, and $b$ is not the same as either of them.

(Though I should point out, it is possible, without further specification on the problem, for $a = b$; just because we have two different names for an element of a set, doesn't mean they are different elements. But, I really don't think this is the point of the exercise. It's also potentially possible for $b$ to be a set in itself, though typically we do not permit sets to contain themselves, so $b = \{b, c\}$ would not be allowed.)

So no, just because $\{b\}$ is a subset of one of the **elements** of $\{a, \{b, c\}\}$, does not mean it is a subset of $\{a, \{b, c\}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are *absolutely* correct.

$b$ is *not* an element of the set so $\{b\}$ is not a subset.  That is all.  If a some of the elements of a set are sets, then those sets are element.  The elements *within* those elements are .... completely irrelevant.

Your set has *two* elments they are $a$ and $\{b,c\}$.  Neither $b$ nor $c$ have anything to do with them.

Your set is $\{a,\{b,c\}\}$.  And it has $2$ elements.  So it has $2^2=4$ subsets.  They are $\emptyset,  \{a\},  \{b,c\},  \{a,\{b,c\}$.

If it helps, imagine $A =a$ and $B = \{b,c\}$.  Then your set is ... $\{A,B\}$.  And its subsets are $\emptyset, \{A\},\{B\}, \{A,B\}$.

It really is that simple.  It seems like having elements being sets could complicate with *their* elements.  But we *isolate* that and *don't* concern ourselves about that.  Sets are *very* rigidly and hierarchically constructed.

So... Anyway,  .... praise to you on your thoughtful and correct deductions.